# Scipy curve_fit confusion using bounds and initial parameters on simple data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

while I've gotten great fits for other datasets, for some reason the following code is not working for a relatively simple set of points. I've tried both a decaying exponential and power, along with initial parameters and bounds. I believe this is exposing my deeper misunderstanding; I appreciate any advice.

```
    snr = [1e10, 5, 1, .5, .1, .05]
    tau = [1, 8, 10, 14, 35, 80]

    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

    def fit(x, a, b, c): #c: asymptote
        #return a * np.exp(b * x) + 1.
        return np.power(x,a)*b + c

    xlist = np.arange(0,len(snr),1)
    p0 = [-1., 1., 1.]
    params = curve_fit(fit, xlist, tau, p0)#, bounds=([-np.inf, 0., 0.], [0., np.inf, np.inf]))

    a, b, c = params[0]
    print(a,b,c)
    ax1.plot(xlist, fit(xlist, a, b, c), c='b', label='Fit')

    #ax1.plot(snr, tau, zorder=-1, c='k', alpha=.25)
    ax1.scatter(snr, tau)
    ax1.set_xscale('log')        
    #ax1.set_xlim(.02, 15)
    plt.show()
```

---

**Update 1:** reference figure, following Eric M's code:
[image: Figure]
Will comment in the post below.

---

**Fix for Update 1:** `xlist = np.arange(0.01,10000,1)/1000+0.01`

Comment: Are you sure you want to be fitting ```xlist```? Your code makes it seem like you want to fit ```snr``` and ```tau```. Then plot the fit across ```xlist```. In that case, you would need to change the fitting line to ```curve_fit(fit, snr, tau, p0)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. There were a couple issues. Including my comment. There is also a 'divide by zero' error in your xlist, so I avoided that by adding 0.01 to `xlist`, and increasing the density of points so the curve is rounded.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

snr = [1e10, 5, 1, .5, .1, .05]
tau = [1, 8, 10, 14, 35, 80]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

def fit(x, a, b, c):
    return np.power(x, a)*b + c

xlist = np.arange(0.01,10000,1)/1000+0.01
xlist = np.append(xlist, 1e10)
p0 = [-10, 10., 1.]
params = curve_fit(fit, snr, tau, p0)

print('Fitting parameters: {}'.format(params[0]))
ax1.plot(xlist, fit(xlist, *params[0]), c='b', label='Fit')
ax1.scatter(snr, tau)
ax1.set_xscale('log')        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I completely overlooked that `xlist` misplacement. Your fit looks great, but using your code exactly (copy and paste), I'm getting a different output (see my original post). What were your params? Perhaps I need to set bounds

Comment: never mind, I made the change: `xlist = np.arange(0.01,10000,1)/1000+0.01`; If you update your code, I'll accept. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Updated it. Glad we could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def fit(x, a, b, c):
    return np.power(x, a)*b + c


x = [1e10, 5, 1, .5, .1, .05]
y = [1, 8, 10, 14, 35, 80]

popt, pcov=curve_fit(fit,x,y, bounds=([-np.inf, 0., 0.], [0., np.inf, np.inf]))
x_curve = np.append(np.linspace(0.01, 10, 1000), 1e11)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-25,100)
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x_curve, np.power(x_curve, popt[0])*popt[1] + popt[2], color = 'green')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. the fit in Eric M's comment is more on point, but also I'm having trouble reproducing. I can however reproduce this plot. Will keep you updated